# cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end - irregularly

Tags: file, google-apps-script, iterator, drive, getfiles

I've got a Script which is creating a PDF from a Google Form and saving it to a specific folder. This works totally fine.

Another Script should get the file in the specific folder by name to send it as an attachment. Everytime this Script runs, there will **always** be **one unique** file.
However, sometimes the Script runs into the exception "cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end" at line "var PDF_Participation", although there is indeed the desired file. If I run the Script manually up to the "critical line" and log the name of the file, it will log the correct file name. I really cannot understand why the Script runs into failure irregularly.

```
//get the email template from google doc using the url of the file
var templateUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I4igdjEYeV46fGbo_MiMClrmJGUrN73ZByCvNBvIVxM/edit'

//Get that template
var template = DocumentApp.openByUrl(templateUrl)

//Extract the text in the body of the document
var text = template.getBody().getText()

//Define Variables from Sheet
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jGQMmLykfnL7t6JNQ7ZzRSlvEDQBJwvqMxCRpNYtZ20");
var FormResponses = sSheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var LastRowRes = FormResponses.getRange(["A1:A"]).getValues().filter(String).length;

var Firstname= FormResponses.getRange(LastRowRes,3).getValue();
var Lastname = FormResponses.getRange(LastRowRes, 4).getDisplayValue();
var Id = FormResponses.getRange(LastRowRes, 5).getDisplayValue();
var Recipient = FormResponses.getRange(LastRowRes,2).getValue();
var Subject = "Participation"
  
var PDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Y9fhQQjbfBu83Vq1UbvZFB3Cdub9dFGI");
var PDF_Participation = PDFfolder.getFilesByName(Id+" "+Lastname+", "+Firstname+" - Participation").next();

//send mails
var emailBody = text.replace('{Firstname}', Firstname)

MailApp.sendEmail(Recipient, Subject, emailBody, {
  noReply: true,
  name: "Organization Team",
  replyTo: "example@google.com",
  attachments: [PDF_Participation.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  })}
```

Can someone please help? :)

Comment: What is the iterator? Please provide the necessary parts of your code.

Comment: The iteratir is next() in following line: var PDF_Participation = PDFfolder.getFilesByName(Id+" "+Lastname+", "+Firstname+" - Participation").next() (see Script provided above)

Comment: No, `next()` is not an iterator. `getFilesByName` is but you are not iterating it. [Supposed to have a `while`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Okay thank you! I'm an absolute beginner in that area. So I'll try to do this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to get your data from the last row.  Instead you should use the event object to get your data.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't possible to do that due to the process requirements. It is only possible to get the data from last row of the sheet...

Comment: What happens when you get nearly simultaneous onFormSubmit triggers.  You will end up looking at the wrong row.